# Hard drive won't stop spinning, even though it is set to turn off and no Programm is using it

Tags: windows, hard-drive, silent-cooling

I am trying to get my PC to be silent. Unfortunately, there is one physical drive (HDD) that just wont stop spinning (and therefore makes a lot of noise). It is only used for data storage, there is no active program that is using the drive. Windows and all the applications I'm using are installed on other drives (SSDs).

The drive is set to be stopped after three minutes of inactivity - yet it will happily spin along for hours:

[image: screenshot - Drive sleep settings]

Ressource Monitor shows no Programm using the drive:

[image: screenshot - Resource Monitor]

Does someone have any Idea what might be causing the drive to stay active and how I might fix this?

I am using windows 10, MSI B350 Motherboard, ryzen 1600. The drive in question is a 2TB Seagate.

Comment: Is there any chance the the particular power plan (High Performance) is not the active one when the drive keeps spinning? Also, you might try a third-party tool such as revoSleep, https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/ , though I've not used it myself.

Comment: Is the Windows virus checker looking at the disk? It runs at a service in the background.

Comment: And indexing on the disk is disabled? If not - then it will constantly index the contents in the background. Plus background checking for viruses.

Comment: "makes a lot of noise" relative to what? Unless the machine is entirely fanless, you'd need your ear right next to an HDD to hear it spinning. Simply closing the case should be sufficient to damp it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I checked, the right power plan is active.

Comment: @Aganju not that I know of - it doesn't show up in resource monitor at least. How would I find out?

Comment: @Alex_Krug yes, indexing is disabled.

Comment: @Tetsujin The PC has a passively cooled graphics card, a silent PSU, a overkill CPU heatsink and a case with fans focused on being silent. The HDD is the loudest by an order of magnitude, case open or closed.